# Page not found in django, pycharm?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am working with django project to create a website 
when i set the first url it works properly but when i add new url after products/new/ then it shows page not found

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/new/
Using the URLconf defined in pyshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

**Here is folders,**

```
products.urls.py:

from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('new', views.new)
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
return HttpResponse('Hello world')


def new(request):
return HttpResponse('New Products!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
```

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductsConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'products'
```

pyshop.urls.py:

```
"""pyshop URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

And here is the error

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/new/ Using the URLconf defined in
>   pyshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/
>  products/
>  products/ new

The current path, products/new/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089666/page-not-found-404-error-in-django-logout-function/62089896?noredirect=1#comment109815723_62089896) help?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: show your project directory and full trace back code thanks.

Comment: actually i don't know what to send i am very new to programming,
Can you tell me what exactly i've to send please.. help me!!! @MuhammadFaizanFareed

Comment: Project  folders and error screenshot which you are getting on console  then we can trace your error thanks. like this  https://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure.html

Comment: i've send views.py urls of both products and pyshop(project) and apps.py and the error text which i get 
 i've pasted in question only you can see that and please get me out of that
please!!!!!
@MuhammadFaizanFareed

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

Use singular name instead of plurals for your apps:

product instead of products.

---

**Templates directory**

First create templates directory into your products app and then create another directory in templates folder name must be your app name (products).

```
products # app name 
   templates # templates folder
       products # again app name
          aboutme.html # here your all html pages
          mypage2.html
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')

def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New Products!!!!!!!!!!!!!')

#or if you want to return html page then 
def aboutme(request):
   return render(request,'products/aboutme.html')
```

**product app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('new', views.new),
path('all-about-me/', views.aboutme,name = 'about_me'), # get rid of hard coded urls so always use name parameter to give some name to your view.  
]
```

**Project urls.py file**

Add here all apps urls.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

**Add your app into setting**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # others goes here

    'products.apps.ProductsConfig',# your products app

]
```

---

Your project directories must be like above as well as code.

You are missing any above step which i described above and confusing in URLS.

http://127.0.0.1:8000 it shows PageNotFound 404 because you are not defined any index page into main URLS.py

http://127.0.0.1:8000/products it shows 'Hello world' (called index view).

http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/new it shows  'New Products!!!!!!!!!!!!!' (called new view).

http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/all-about-me it render aboutme.html (called aboutme view )

**still confused leave a comment.**

Comment: please explain how to execute that template creation step in product app!!!! @Muhammad Faizan Fareed

Comment: What do you mean  ? Like how to create html page template or templates directory ? Or how page served from start to end ?